# Optuna 3.2 + Optuna Dashboard 0.10.3 - study page going blank (content dissappears)

Tags: python-3.x, firefox, browser-cache, optuna

I had an issue with Optuna 3.2 + Optuna Dashboard 0.10.3 (using Firefox as my browser - the issue would probably be the same in other browsers). While I opened the study page, something appeared briefly, but then it disappeared, and only a blank page remained. I reinstalled everything, tried to change libraries related to it...

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was actually just wiping out the cache of my browser. I realize this is nothing too complicated, but this idea did not occur to me (that the cache could somehow brake it - probably because of the new layout), and I think it might not occur to others. I struggled for 2 good hours and stumbled upon the solution by sheer luck.